# PHP get real time date without page reload

Tags: php, jquery, date

I have some code that gets the server date and time in PHP which works well. But I need it to work all the time rather than on page load...

Code is below:

```
<?php
if(date('w') !== 0) {
  if((current_time('Hi')<1800 && current_time('Hi')>=1400) || (current_time('Hi')<1300 && current_time('Hi')>=700)) {
    echo 'We are Open';
  }
  else {
    echo 'We are Closed';
  }
}
else if(intval(current_time('Hi'))<1230 && current_time('Hi')>=700) {
  echo 'We are Open';
}
else {
  echo 'We are Closed';
}
?>




<p>We close at <strong>

<?php
if (date('l') != "Sunday") {
    echo '18:00';
} else if (date('l') == "Sunday") {
    echo '12:30';
}
?>

</strong> today</p>
```

Is it possible to make this work to poll the server / work after the page loads - so for example, if on a Monday the page is loaded at 17:58 and the user views the page for 3 minutes, the code should change the sign from showing OPEN to CLOSED without the need for a page refresh.

Will I need to abandon this route and use jQuery instead?

Appreciate any insight.

Cheers

Comment: Yes, you will have to use jQuery / JS.

Comment: Just do it in javascript rather than constantly hit your server just to get a time update

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use jQuery - but you would need to use JS code to either make an AJAX request or monitor a websocket connection, depending on the level of synchronicity you require.

Comment: OK thanks guys. Will see what I can do in jQuery then

Comment: Other option would be to give server timezone to javascript on page load, and then make all time calculations in javascript, without querying server at all

Answer (score 0):

You need create a new PHP file in server which will return you the current time and using ajax you need to make xhr request to the php file that you have created in server